# How to build up correct numerical model for osculating orbit?

Tags: astrophysics, celestial-mechanics

The situation is that I want to make a numerical model of rstricted 3-body problem (heavy body on a fixed position, one massive body with known law of motion and one lightweight whose motion I want to study). I have differential equations for keplerian elements of orbit:
$$
\dot{e} = \varkappa e \sqrt{1 - e^2}\sin^2(i)\sin(\omega)\cos(\omega)\\ \frac{di}{dt} = -\varkappa \frac{e^2}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}\sin(i)\cos(i)\sin(\omega)\cos(\omega) \\ \dot{\Omega} = -\frac{\varkappa\cos(i)}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}(e^2\sin^2(\omega) + \frac{1-e^2}{5}) \\ \dot{\omega} = \frac{\varkappa}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}(~(e^2 - \sin^2(i))\sin^2(\omega) + 0.4(1-e^2)~)  \\ \dot{M} = n - \frac{1- e^2}{nea^2}\cdot \frac{3\omega_0 a^2 e}{4}(1+\sin^2(i) - 5\sin^2(\omega)sin^2(i))
$$
Where $ \varkappa = const, n = const, \omega_0 = const$, $i, \Omega, \omega$ - Euler angles of the orbit of lightweight body and $e$ is eccentricity of this orbit (major semiaxis $a$ is constant), $M$ - mean anomaly of the body. The question is how to scale thiese equations correctly to make a model? The original goal of my work to study the influence of Titan on Hyperion's motion, and I don't understand how to scale the parameters of the bodies and the time to make model work in reasonable time.

Comment: It looks to me like $\varkappa$ sets the timescale. What value are you using for it?

Comment: @Ghoster I guess no, this parameter depends only on initial angular speed of a massive body (it's constant) , masses and semiaxes length

Comment: You guess that $\varkappa$ *doesn’t* set the timescale? In the first four equations for rates of change of various dimensionless parameters, $\varkappa$ is the *only* dimensional quantity. So if it doesn’t set the timescale for their change, what does?

Comment: To put it more simply: Your equations require $\varkappa$ to have dimensions of inverse time (e.g., units of 1/sec).

Comment: I tried osculating some female objects during grad school but had very little luck with it.

Comment: Oh, my fault, now I see, that's much easier than I expected it to be, thank you!